# How to create a floating button in the right corner of a screen using nativedroid2 library?

Tags: android, jquery, html, css, cordova

I am using cordova with jquery mobile and nativedroid2 libraries. I want to create a floating button on the bottom right of a screen (like we have in gmail app). I am not able to do the part where I have to declare it a floating button.

```html
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-btn-right ui-btn-fab" style="background-color:rgb(100,200,250);"><i class="zmdi zmdi-plus zmd-2x"></i></a>
```

How do I go about it?

Comment: I know that a specific button class must be added to make this happen, but really have no idea what that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the floating button inside your main container. If you are using nativedroid2 with jQuery mobile below is the code example you may use -

```
    <!-- message page -->
<div data-role="page" id="messages-page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" data-tap-toggle="false">
        <h1>Messages</h1>
    </div> <!-- /header-->
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="listMessage" data-role="listview" data-icon="false" class="ui-listview" data-inset="true">
            <li class="ui-li-has-thumb">
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn waves-effect waves-button waves-effect waves-button">
                    <h2>Amit Anmol</h2>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="ui-li-has-thumb">
                <a href="#" class="ui-btn waves-effect waves-button waves-effect waves-button">
                    <h2>Amit Anmol</h2>
                    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

        <!-- floating button -->
        <a id="btn-compmsg" href="#compose-msg-page" class="ui-btn-fab ui-btn-raised clr-warning ui-btn ui-btn-inline waves-effect waves-button waves-effect waves-button" data-transition="flow">
            <i class='zmdi zmdi-plus zmd-2x'></i>
        </a>
    </div> <!-- /content -->
</div><!-- /message page -->
```

And the output of this code is

[image: output]